# Can I download on Xbox 360 after disconnecting the HDMI cable?

Tags: xbox-360

I want to know if my download will continue even if I disconnect my HDMI cable from my Xbox 360. I have a download going on but I need the display for something else.

Comment: try it for yourself? Really isn't that hard to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HDMI cable for video game consoles only provides audio and video it is okay to unplug the HDMI cable, however I would never recommend pulling out any electronic cables while the console is on. So yes you can disconnect the HDMI cable and continue your download.

I would recommend instead buying an HDMI switch so you can have multiple HDMI devices attached to your display device.

Comment: @kiran if this answer has helped you solve your problem you may click the green check mark on this answer to say that this answer answered your question. This helps future people who may have this same question.