# Can I continue my download on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I have a digital game code of forza horizon 2.Its will take a long time for me to download so can I pause the download and resume later like in torrents?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: I haven't tried so just asking

Comment: Like I said on your [last question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/305132/can-i-download-on-xbox-360-after-disconnecting-the-hdmi-cable), try for yourself? It's not that hard to test. It should resume the download where you left off after unpausing.

Comment: Okay I will try and see for my self

Comment: @kiran After you test it, you can answer your own question. The question may not get any upvotes for being simple, but you could get upvotes for the answer still.

Comment: Bittorrent doesn't actually allow resumable downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does. The download will continue even after the console is turned off. But you must not erase the downloaded data

Comment: You can Accept your own answer too — that will mark this Question as being answered and take it off the list of unanswered ones.